# Build a global model based on thousand local models

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have 1000 meters for electricity usage. I want to train one global model for all of them to predict their consumption for the next few days. So, when I train the model with all of the meter data, the prediction is not good. But when I train the model for each one separately, the prediction is good. So, I am looking for a way to train 1000 model with these ids, and then with these 1000 model, I create one global model. Is it doable? Do you have any thoughts regarding this? Thank you.